# Scope of For Loop Variable Javascript

Tags: variables, for-loop, scope

When you write out a for loop in javascript like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //code
}
```

is the variable "i" considered global or local?  It's not in a function so I'm assuming it's global?  Is it wrong then to add another for loop further down the page using the same iterator "i"?  Should you name the variable something else?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in the global scope (i.e. not in a function), then the variable is global.

If you reuse the variable further down in the code, then just omit the `var`. Declaring the same variable again doesn't cause a problem, but it looks like you are not aware that the variable already exists.

Reusing variables can sometimes make the code harder to follow, but on the other hand in your case it helps to keep the number of global variables down.